# Issues with ExperienceExtractor module for Sitecore 8.2 Update 5

Tags: experience-analytics

I am trying to integrate the Experience extractor module in our project.

https://github.com/Sitecore/experience-extractor

We are using Sitecore 8.2 update 5.

When I build the ExperienceExtractor solution, it built successfully. After that, I deployed the DLLs into our Sitecore instance, clicked Submit in the ExtractorAdmin page and it threw this error.

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: No parse factory
>   registered for type IDataSource with key "xdb" (Source)    at
>   ExperienceExtractor.Api.Parsing.JsonJobParser.Parse[TType](ParseState
>   state) in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Parsing\JsonJobParser.cs:line
>   67    at
>   ExperienceExtractor.Api.Parsing.JobParser.ParseDataSource(ParseState
>   state) in
>   C:\Users\gantarao.pala\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Parsing\JobParser.cs:line
>   69    at ExperienceExtractor.Api.Parsing.JobParser.CreateDataSource()
>   in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Parsing\JobParser.cs:line
>   134    at ExperienceExtractor.Api.Jobs.Job.Run() in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Jobs\Job.cs:line
>   109
>
> {   "Id": "cc00ebd6-a6c6-4950-a7f6-747b25b2d754",   "Created":
>   "2018-11-09T09:27:58.6951558+05:30",   "Ended":
>   "2018-11-09T09:27:58.7679627+05:30",   "ItemsProcessed": 0,
>   "RowsCreated": 0,   "Progress": null,   "Status": "Failed",
>   "StatusText": "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: No
>   parse factory registered for type IDataSource with key \"xdb\"
>   (Source)\r\n   at
>   ExperienceExtractor.Api.Parsing.JsonJobParser.Parse[TType](ParseState
>   state) in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Parsing\JsonJobParser.cs:line 67\r\n   at
>   ExperienceExtractor.Api.Parsing.JobParser.ParseDataSource(ParseState
>   state) in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Parsing\JobParser.cs:line
>   69\r\n   at
>   ExperienceExtractor.Api.Parsing.JobParser.CreateDataSource() in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Parsing\JobParser.cs:line
>   134\r\n   at ExperienceExtractor.Api.Jobs.Job.Run() in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Jobs\Job.cs:line
>   109",   "SizeLimitExceeded": false,   "Url":
>   "/sitecore/experienceextractor/jobs/cc00ebd6-a6c6-4950-a7f6-747b25b2d754",
>   "Specification": "{\r\n  \"source\": {\r\n    \"xdb\": {\r\n
>   \"filters\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"sample\": 0.3\r\n
>   },\r\n        {\r\n          \"daterange\": {\r\n
>   \"start\": \"2018-10-01Z\",\r\n            \"end\":
>   \"2018-11-30Z\"\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n 
>   },\r\n  \"mapper\": {},\r\n  \"postprocessors\": [\r\n
>   \"msaccess\"\r\n  ]\r\n}",   "LastException":
>   "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: No parse factory
>   registered for type IDataSource with key \"xdb\" (Source)\r\n   at
>   ExperienceExtractor.Api.Parsing.JsonJobParser.Parse[TType](ParseState
>   state) in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Parsing\JsonJobParser.cs:line 67\r\n   at
>   ExperienceExtractor.Api.Parsing.JobParser.ParseDataSource(ParseState
>   state) in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Parsing\JobParser.cs:line
>   69\r\n   at
>   ExperienceExtractor.Api.Parsing.JobParser.CreateDataSource() in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Parsing\JobParser.cs:line
>   134\r\n   at ExperienceExtractor.Api.Jobs.Job.Run() in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\experience-extractor-master\experience-extractor-master\src\ExperienceExtractor\Api\Jobs\Job.cs:line
>   109" }

I have tried these troubleshooting steps:

1. Replaced existing MongoDB.Driver.dll with new one v2.4.4.0.
2. Replaced existing MongoDB.Bson.dll with new one v2.4.4.0.
3. Built the Extractor solution which failed.
4. Tried @massimde 's suggestion from [here](https://github.com/Sitecore/experience-extractor/issues/14) which is this:

*Change the ExperienceExtractor.MongoDb.Helpers class as follows:*

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FastSpool<T>(this MongoCursor<RawBsonDocument> cursor, int threads = 2){
        var binaryReaderSettings = new BsonBinaryReaderSettings(); 
        binaryReaderSettings.MaxDocumentSize = int.MaxValue;
        var serializer = BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(T));

        return cursor
            .AsParallel().AsOrdered()
                .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(Math.Max(1, threads))
            .Select(doc =>
            {                    
                using (doc)
                {
                    using (var stream = new ByteBufferStream(doc.Slice))
                    using (var reader = new BsonBinaryReader(stream, binaryReaderSettings))
                    {
                        var context = BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(reader);
                        return (T) serializer.Deserialize(context);
                    }
                    // Old code
                    //return (T)serializer.Deserialize(new BsonBinaryReader(new BsonBuffer(doc.Slice, false), binaryReaderSettings),
                    //    typeof(T), null);
                }
            });   
    }
```

The solution could not find the namespaces for a few like

```
MongoCursor<RawBsonDocument>, doc, query
```

Please advise.